# How do I regain access to Font Book? It opens, hangs, then requires Force Quit

Tags: performance, font-book

I just purchased a new MacBook Pro and migrated everything over from the old one. I had imagined that it was the old one that was preventing me from being able use Font Book (`Font Book.app`); it’s not that.

When I attempt to open it on the new machine, looks like it is going to work for about five seconds, then becomes completely non–responsive, including the spinning wait cursor, until I use Force Quit.

So far I have tried deleting

1. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontBook.plist`,
2. `~/Library/Preferences/Saved Application State/com.apple.FontBook.savedState`, and
3. [`~/Library/Fonts`](//apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176674/how-do-i-regain-access-to-font-book-it-opens-hangs-then-requires-force-quit#comment208687_176674),

and then rebooting, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a lot of non-apple fonts added to your machine?  If so, try temporarily removing them.

Comment: I’m not sure which one’s were which—I used to be kinda hasty about adding new ones every time I saw [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/?oldid=651089408) in Wikipedia entries.

Based on their Last Modified dates, I’m assuming it’s probably only those in `~/Library/Fonts` (but not those in `/Library/Fonts` or in `/System/Library/Fonts`, right? Can I simply delete `~/Library/Fonts` temporarily? Sounds risky.

Comment: Just move everything in ~/Library/Fonts to a folder on your desktop and restart and see if fontbook will work right

Comment: I tried deleting the fonts in `~/Library/Fonts` and Font Book still opens, then hangs until I use Force Quit. The question is [edited accordingly](//apple.stackexchange.com/posts/176674/revisions).

Comment: . . . and for what it’s worth, during the seconds right after I open it, but before the hang begins, the pane on the left briefly shows four items before quickly hiding the last one (it’s so fast that I had to try a couple times before I could make out what it said). There’s “All Fonts” then a subheading “Smart Collection” with one entry (“English”). The item that comes and goes is another subheading called “Collections”; it is empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a backup of `/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/FontCollections`, and then delete that folder. Most likely, it's a corrupt font collection. Then, recreate the folder, and add each one back if you really want to investigate.

Otherwise, just delete the collections and start over.

Comment: It worked! It was as simple as removing `~/Library/FontCollections`. Thank you :-)

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to El Capitan Font Book crashed - EVERY time I launched it. Though I couldn't delete the Font Collections folder, I could remove all of the items in it. AND IT WORKED! Font Book is now as it should be. Oh Happy Day!

Answer (score 2):

A variation of suggestions from Alistair and Kevin and the Lucas, the OP, worked for me.

This is exactly the problem I was having. From Lucas: Before the hang begins, the pane on the left briefly shows four items ... “All Fonts” then a subheading “Smart Collection.”

I force-quite Font Book, went to the FontCollections folder (Finder Go Menu, pasted ~/Library/FontCollections).

Sorting by date added, there were some from the day of the crash. I threw those four font collection into the trash, and was able to reboot Font Book without a hitch.

To be safe I should probably trash them all, but for a quick fix this got me back in business.

Comment: Font Book crashed on me while I was creating a new Smart Collection, and since then it would crash on launch. I could just delete the collection that caused the original crash and everything was OK again.